# Using nested reduces on an object by properties

Tags: javascript

I have data like this:

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, cat: "human", age: "10" },
  { id: 2, cat: "human", age: "20" },
  { id: 3, cat: "human", age: "10" },
  { id: 4, cat: "animal", age: "10" },
  { id: 5, cat: "animal", age: "20" },
  { id: 6, cat: "animal", age: "10" },
  { id: 7, cat: "alien", age: "10" },
  { id: 8, cat: "alien", age: "20" },
  { id: 9, cat: "alien", age: "10" },
];
```

I want to group this data something like that:

```
const gr = {
  human: {
    all: [
      { id: 1, cat: "human", age: "10" },
      { id: 2, cat: "human", age: "20" },
      { id: 3, cat: "human", age: "10" },
    ],
    ages: {
      "10": [
        { id: 1, cat: "human", age: "10" },
        { id: 3, cat: "human", age: "10" },
      ],
      "20": [
        { id: 2, cat: "human", age: "20" },
      ],
    }
  },
  animal: {...},
  alien: {...},
}
```

I do first reduce like that:

```
const gr = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const { cat } = el;
  acc[cat] = acc[cat] || { all: [] };
  acc[cat].all.push(el);

  return acc;
}, {});
```

But I can't make a nested reduce here. I can do it separately like that:

```
const grAge = gr.human.all.reduce((acc,el) => {
    const {age} = el;
    acc[age] = acc[age] || [];
    acc[age].push(el);

    return acc;
  },{});

gr.human["ages"] = grAge;
```

But obviously, this is not so efficient and needs more work. Maybe like this:

```
Object.keys(gr).forEach(key => {
  const grAge = gr[key].all.reduce((acc,el) => {
    const {age} = el;
    acc[age] = acc[age] || [];
    acc[age].push(el);

    return acc;
  },{});

  gr[key]["ages"] = grAge;
});
```

Can I join those reduces in a single step?

If there are any other good methods I can use them, I don't need to use the reduce method.

Comment: can you type what exactly you expect, because "something like" it's not definitely term?

Comment: It is already in the answer. See: `const gr = ...` below "something like that" phrase.

Comment: You have to do it separately. Nothing there to make it inline nested. But maybe you should create separate function with meaningful names.

Comment: Thank you @Oliver for your suggestion. I am tearing my hair out here for some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a sinle loop approach and assign the wanted structure to either `all`or to a nested strcture.

If you like to get a more dynamic version, you need to simplify the result structure for every nesting level (this means, the age level would contain an `all` property).

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, cat: "human", age: "10" }, { id: 2, cat: "human", age: "20" }, { id: 3, cat: "human", age: "10" }, { id: 4, cat: "animal", age: "10" }, { id: 5, cat: "animal", age: "20" }, { id: 6, cat: "animal", age: "10" }, { id: 7, cat: "alien", age: "10" }, { id: 8, cat: "alien", age: "20" }, { id: 9, cat: "alien", age: "10" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.cat] = r[o.cat] || { all: [], ages: {} };        
        r[o.cat].all.push(o);
        r[o.cat].ages[o.age] = r[o.cat].ages[o.age] || [];
        r[o.cat].ages[o.age].push(o);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Learned something else about reduce from this.

Comment: I was hoping to see you around here :) Nailed it, thank you. Weird thing, I swear I tried something like this. When I see your code I said, "Oh I tried that one." Now I can't find where was the problem but your code solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to get every unique category and ages using Sets, and then reducing them into your final JSON :

EDIT : It seems like the Stack Overflow snippet doesn't like it, but executing it in your browser console will give out the correct result

```js
const data = [
 { id: 1, cat: "human", age: "10" },
 { id: 2, cat: "human", age: "20" },
 { id: 3, cat: "human", age: "10" },
 { id: 4, cat: "animal", age: "10" },
 { id: 5, cat: "animal", age: "20" },
 { id: 6, cat: "animal", age: "10" },
 { id: 7, cat: "alien", age: "10" },
 { id: 8, cat: "alien", age: "20" },
 { id: 9, cat: "alien", age: "10" },
];

const output = [...new Set(data.map(thing => thing.cat))].reduce((acc, category) => {
 const catData = data.filter(thing => thing.cat === category)

 return {
  [category]: {
   all: catData,
   ages : [...new Set(catData.map(catThing => catThing.age))].reduce((catAcc, age) => ({
    [age]: [...catData.filter(catThing => catThing.age === age)],
    ...catAcc
   }), {})
  },
  ...acc
 }
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: btw, [JSON](https://json.org/) is always a string. the structure is just an object with other objects or arrays.